# Vue.js web application using a Node.js connection with mysql-ssh

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, ssh, npm-run

I am working on a course project using Vue.js to create the front-end web application.  I am extremely new with how the front and back ends speak to each other.  My teammate created the Node.js code below (sensitive information left out):

```
const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');
var commands = require('./commandList');
var command = commands.cmd;
var output;
mysqlssh.connect(
    {
        host: 'address',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'pwd'
    },
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'pws',
        database: 'db-name'
    }
)
.then(client => {
    client.query(command, function (err, results, fields) {//command is query
        if (err) throw err//throws error if anything in the connection goes wrong
        console.log(results);//logs results of query
        output = JSON.stringify(results);//output = results of query
       // var i = output.lastIndexOf('"');//gets last "
       // output = output.slice(0, i);//slices off last " and everything after it
        //i = output.lastIndexOf('"');//gets new last "
       // output = output.slice(i+1, output.length);//slices new last " and everything before it
       // console.log(output);//prints output to console
        mysqlssh.close()//close sql ssh
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    })
```

The file works just fine when running `node db.js`

However, when I attempt to use `import` or `require` or even copy and paste this into my App.vue file, the project throws a compile error that is not descriptive: 
WARNING: in ./node_modules/defaultable/defaultable.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression 
[Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CspWI.jpg)
And when viewing the project within the browser, I see this error in the Console: 
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'net'. 
[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQd2.jpg) 
This appears it is part of the `net` module of Node.js and as I understand it, this cannot run on the browser.  I am not looking for code critique, but I would like to know if there is a way to implement this setup without reworking the code that connects to the MySQL database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer after hours of toiling is to standup another package that runs node server separately using Express as a router ending up with something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');

const router = express.Router();

var output;

// Get App User
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM APPUSERS WHERE EMAIL = 'sample@email.com';";
    var result = connectAndQuery(query);
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send(output);
    }, 3000);
});




function connectAndQuery(command) {
    mysqlssh.connect(
        {
            host: 'address',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'pwd'
        },
        {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'pwd',
            database: 'db-name'
        }
    )
        .then(client => {
            client.query(command, function (err, results) {//command is query
                if (err) throw err;//throws error if anything in the connection goes wrong
                output = JSON.stringify(results);

                mysqlssh.close();//close sql ssh
                return output;
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

module.exports = router;
```